# Authentication with (content-type: application/x-wamf)

Tags: php, authentication

While I was writing an app to provide stats for one game, I noticed this content type in the login form:

```
content-type: application/x-wamf
```

I never saw it before and the output sent to the server (not with real credentials) is something like this:

```
xœÁK
Â0ÐT¡‚Á•[ÝF’ÉäwI&“Zhli^ß÷Ä3Oä˜G—Á§@&YrÑš0‰Dð5JÌÅJD´2Fï%QQÖêR5:1ºÀ&V¨RUŸ%42d­¤-^9TÆB@qû¬·4ñkY§ù{º[š—þ¢ÁÜ·t¿u/ýé±sã–y7îÏºûo+ø
```

Does anyone know how to work with this?